# Styling framer-motion-carousel in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I am using Carousel from 'framer-motion-carousel'
I don't really like the style of the arrows and the dots!
I don't wanna hide them , i want to style them.

the [docs](https://www.framer.com/developers/) isn't really helpful !

the carousel component have these props :

```
export type CarouselProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    renderArrowLeft?: (args: {
        handlePrev: () => void;
        activeIndex: number;
    }) => React.ReactNode;
    renderArrowRight?: (args: {
        handleNext: () => void;
        activeIndex: number;
    }) => React.ReactNode;
    renderDots?: (args: Omit<DotProps, 'length'>) => React.ReactNode;
    autoPlay: boolean;
    interval: number;
    loop: boolean;
};
```

i tried to play around with that but didn't really get any progress